# How can I plot a Hohmann Transfer Orbit in MATLAB using ode45?

Tags: matlab, plot, physics, ode, orbital-mechanics

In my code below I have vectors r and v, `r = [r1, 0, 0] v = [0, sqrt(mu/r1), 0]` which define the initial position and velocity of the spacecraft. I want to use ode45 on r(double dot)=-(mu)*r/rmag^3 which defines a two body problem. My objective is to plot a Hohmann transfer of the spacecraft from Earth to an asteroid and any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
function Asteroid_Mining
clc

%Initial conditions
g0 = 9.81; %gravity (m/s^2)
p = 1.225; %atmospheric density at sea level (kg/m3)
Re = 6378; %radius of Earth (km) 
Ra = 7.431e7; %distance of Bennu from Earth in (km) [August 2023]
G = 6.674e-11/1e9; % Gravitational constant (km3/kg.s2)
mu = 3.986e5; %gravitational parameter (km3/s2)
Me = 5.972e24; %mass of Earth (kg)
Ma = 7.8e10; %Mass of asteroid (kg)
Ms = 2110; %launch mass of spacecraft (kg)
Isp = 230; %specific impulse (s)
tspan = [0 10000]; %time at 0s

%% Relative to a non-rotating Earth-centred Cartesian coordinate system [0 0 0]

ar = [Re+Ra, 0, 0];
av = [0, 10000, 10000];

r1 = Re+500;
r2 = r1+Ra;

r = [r1, 0, 0]; %initial position of the spacecraft
v = [0, sqrt(mu/r1), 0]; %initial velocity of the spacecraft
rv = [r;v];
h = cross(r,v);
rdoth = cross(v,h)*-1;
rmag = norm(r);
e = (rdoth/mu) - (r/rmag);
emag = norm(e); %eccentricity

%Calculating delta-v for transfer orbit
ve1 = sqrt(mu/r1);
h2 = sqrt(2*mu)*sqrt((r1*r2)/(r1+r2)); 
ve2 = h2/r1;

%Calculating delta-v for Asteroid Orbit
va2 = h2/r2;
va3 = sqrt(mu/r2);
deltaV = norm(ve2-ve1) + norm(va3-va2);
deltaVc = deltaV*1e3;

%mass of propellant consumed
deltaM_M0 = 1 - emag^-(deltaVc/(Isp*g0));
deltaM = deltaM_M0*Ms;

[tout, rvout] = ode45(@Orbit,tspan,rv);

xout = rvout(:,1);
yout = rvout(:,2);
zout = rvout(:,3);
vxout = rvout(:,4);
vyout = rvout(:,4);
vzout = rvout(:,4);


    function drvt = Orbit(t, state)
    r = [r1, 0, 0]; %initial position of the spacecraft
    v = [0, sqrt(mu/r1), 0]; %initial velocity of the spacecraft
    rv = [r,v];
    x = rv(1);
    y = rv(2);
    z = rv(3);
    vx = rv(4);
    vy = rv(5);
    vz = rv(6);

    r = sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2);

    dxdt = x;
    dydt = y;
    dzdt = z;
    dvxdt = -mu*x*(r^-3);
    dvydt = -mu*y*(r^-3);
    dvzdt = -mu*z*(r^-3);
    
    drvt = zeros(size(state));
    drvt(1) = dxdt;
    drvt(2) = dydt;
    drvt(3) = dzdt;
    drvt(4) = dvxdt;
    drvt(5) = dvydt;
    drvt(6) = dvzdt;

    end
end
```

Comment: There is one conceptual issue: you are not in the framework of Kepler's two-body problem. You are in the framework of the restricted three body problem, and in fact, of a restricted four body problem. You have Earth and an asteroid orbiting the sun and on top of that you want a satellite to switch orbits from Earth to satellite. Are you trying to build just a toy model, where everything orbits around the sun on circular orbits and you are switching from "Earth's" circular orbit to "asteroid's" circular orbit?

Comment: I am neglecting the effect of the Sun and treating Earth as the centre of Hohmann Transfer so Earth has coordindates [0 0 0]. My aim is to plot a spacecraft going from Earth to the altitude of the asteroid, Ra = 7.431e7, via a Hohmann transfer. I have added more to my code but I am still having issues plotting the orbit transfer. Also if possible how do you calculate the time of this hohmann transfer?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```matlab
function Numeric_Kepler

G = 6.674e-11/1e9; %gravitational constant
M_Earth = 5.972e24; %mass of Earth
Re = 6378; %radius of Earth (km) 
GM_Earth = G*M_Earth;
dt = 70; %time step in sec
mu = 3.986e5; %gravitational parameter (km3/s2)

r1 = Re+500; %distance between initial position of spacecraft and Earth
%Ra = 7.431e7; %distance of Bennu from Earth in (km) [August 2023]

r_0 = [r1, 0, 0]; %initial position of the spacecraft
v_0 = [0, sqrt(mu/r1), 0]; %initial uncorrected velocity of the spacecraft

dv0 = [0, 1.3, 0]; %velocity correction

r0 = r_0; %initial position of spacecraft
v0 = v_0 + dv0; %corrected initial velocity

%initialization of the dynamical variables
r_ = r_0;
v_ = v_0;
r = r0;
v = v0;

%keepoint the plots in the same window 
hold on
grid on

% setting up the window's shape by definig the coordinate axes' ranges 
r2 = 3*r1;
axis([ -r2 r2 -r2 r2])

% generating the dynamics and potting it at the same time, 
% simple animation style
plot(0, 0, 'ro')
for j = 1:1000
    %propagation along spacraft's uncorrected orbit
    [r_, v_] = Kepler_flow(r_, v_, dt); 
    plot(r_(1), r_(2), 'bo')
    %propagation along spacraft's corrected orbit
    [r, v] = Kepler_flow(r, v, dt);
    plot(r(1), r(2), 'ro')
    pause(0.1)
end



function a = Gravity(x)
   a = - ( (GM_Earth) / norm(x)^3 ) * x; 
end

function [r_1, v_1] = Kepler_step(r, v, dt)
   r_1 =  r   +  (dt/2) * v;
   v_1 =  v   +   dt * Gravity(r_1); 
   r_1 = r_1  +  (dt/2) * v_1;
end

function [r_1, v_1] = Kepler_flow(r, v, dt)
   [r_1, v_1] = Kepler_step(r, v, dt/2);
   [r_1, v_1] = Kepler_step(r_1, v_1, dt);
   [r_1, v_1] = Kepler_step(r_1, v_1, dt/2);
end

end
```

Here is another version that has 4th order convergence of the integrator, the same as that of the explicit Runge-Kutta 4, but this integrator is time reversible and symplecitc (quasi-conserves the systm's energy). Such integrators are quite steady, consistent and fairly accurate for long time-propagations of the dynamics.

```matlab
function Numeric_Kepler

G = 6.674e-11/1e9; %gravitational constant
M_Earth = 5.972e24; %mass of Earth
Re = 6378; %radius of Earth (km) 
GM_Earth = G*M_Earth;
mu = 3.986e5; %gravitational parameter (km3/s2)

% integration parameters
w0 = nthroot(2,3);
w1 = 1 / (2 - w0);
w0 = - w0*w1;
c = [w1, w0+w1 , w0+w1, w1]/2;
d = [w1, w0, w1];

r1 = Re+500; %distance between initial position of spacecraft and Earth
%Ra = 7.431e7; %distance of Bennu from Earth in (km) [August 2023]

dt = 70; %time step in sec
r_0 = [r1; 0; 0]; %initial position of the spacecraft
v_0 = [0; sqrt(mu/r1); 0]; %initial uncorrected velocity of the spacecraft

dv0 = [0; 1.5; 0]; %velocity correction

r0 = r_0; %initial position of spacecraft
v0 = v_0 + dv0; %corrected initial velocity

%initialization of the dynamical variables
r_ = r_0;
v_ = v_0;
v = v0;
r = r0;

%keeping the plots in the same window 
hold on
grid on

% setting up the window's shape by defining the coordinate axes' ranges 
r2 = 3*r1;
axis([ -r2 r2 -r2 r2])

% generating the dynamics and potting it at the same time, 
% simple animation style
plot(0, 0, 'ro')
for j = 1:300
    %propagation along spacecraft's uncorrected orbit
    [r_, v_] = Kepler_flow_4(r_, v_, dt); 
    plot(r_(1), r_(2), 'bo')
    %propagation along spacecraft's corrected orbit
    [r, v] = Kepler_flow_4(r, v, dt);
    plot(r(1), r(2), 'ro')
    pause(0.1)
end



function a = Gravity(x)
   a = - ( (GM_Earth) / norm(x)^3 ) * x; 
end

function [r_1, v_1] = Kepler_flow_4(r, v, dt)
    r_1 = r;
    v_1 = v;
    for i = 1:3
       r_1 = r_1 +  c(i)*dt * v_1;
       v_1 = v_1 +  d(i)*dt * Gravity(r_1); 
    end
    r_1 = r_1  +  c(4)*dt * v_1;
end

end
```